# Why hasn't Twilio added the Location Sharing Template to it's WhatsApp API?

Tags: whatsapp, twilio-api

Meta added the ability to create a CTA button that allows users to share their location with a business. Whilst Twilio is able to receive location data from the attachment menu, there is no option to create a 'card' or CTA for the user to quickly tap to send a location.

Here is an example from another provider showing how this looks - Sprinklr: https://www.sprinklr.com/help/articles/freeform-templates/create-a-request-location-template-for-whatsapp-business/64c398077364b75ac120f80e

[image]

The code block does not look complicated:

```
{"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "type": "interactive",
  "to": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "interactive": {
    "type": "location_request_message",
    "body": {
      "text": "Let us start with your pickup. You can either manually *enter an address* or *share your current location*."
    },
    "action": {
      "name": "send_location"
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any Twilio evangelists that might be able to shed further light on this?